# NodeJS Google Cloud Speech To Text - LongRunningRecognize - Could not load the default credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Cloud Speech To Text in NodeJS. (@google-cloud/speech)

I specified the correct path to the google cloud credentials in process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

The normal recognize works as expected:

```
const [response] = await speechClient.recognize(options);
```

However, the long running recognize throws an error:

```
const [operation] = await speechClient.longRunningRecognize(options);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```

The second line throws the following error:

> Could not load the default credentials.